# Avoid multiple loops in JS implementation of Bonferroni inequality

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops, bonferroni

I was trying to implement the "Bonferroni inequality" which models the probability of the union of many independent events for a data science use case on GCP BigQuery using a Javascript UDF. However I'm quite unfamiliar with JS and have no clue of the good practices.

The formula to apply is the following:

```
P(U Ai) = SUM(P(Ai)) - SUM(P(Ai)*P(Aj)) + SUM(P(Ai)*P(Aj)*P(Ak) - ... i != j != k
```

My input for this function is an array of the single event probabilities:

```
[P(A1), P(A2), P(A3), ...]
```

I instinctively made "for loops" in rows to get the result however, it hurts to see a code this ugly so was wondering if any of you had an idea on how to achieve it in a more elegant and optimized way?

Here is the function I wrote for a level 4 Bonferroni inequality :

```
function unionBoundProbability(probList){

  var intersection2 = 0;
  var intersection3 = 0;
  var intersection4 = 0;
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var k = 0;
  var l = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  var product = 1;

  var sum = probList.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

  for(i = 0; i < probList.length; i++){
    product *= probList[i];
    for(j = i+1; j < probList.length; j++){
      intersection2 += probList[i]*probList[j];
      for(k = j+1; k < probList.length; k++){
        intersection3 += probList[i]*probList[j]*probList[k];
        for(l = k+1; l < probList.length; l++){
          intersection4 += probList[i]*probList[j]*probList[k]*probList[l];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  switch (probList.length) {
    case 0:
      return 0;
      break;
    case 1:
      return probList[0];
      break;
    case 2:
      return sum - product;
      break;
    case 3:
      return sum - intersection2 + product;
      break
    case 4:
      return sum - intersection2 + intersection3 - product;
    case 5 :
      return sum - intersection2 + intersection3 - intersection4 + product;
    default:
      return Math.max((sum - intersection2 + intersection3  - intersection4), Math.max.apply(Math, probList));
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to calculate an approximation of the probability of the union of all the probabilities passed as the input.

If I have less than 5 probabilities, then the switch statement applies the exact formula. Otherwise, the default case applies the Bonferroni approximation, (As I'm modeling the chance of a signal to be received, if the estimation is less than the probability with the best antenna then I keep the best antenna).

Thank you for your help

Comment: I suggest you read up about recursion and implement a recursive function as the solution

Comment: does the code work? do you have some data like `probList` and probably other missing informations and the wanted result?

Comment: You might want to remove the JavaScript tag as this is a general programming question which is not specific to JavaScript

Comment: Is number of levels is an external parameter or should it be derived from probList?

Comment: You don't seem to use `intersection4` in the return value...

Comment: How does the final constant term depend on the level? Woud level 5 have `+ 0.5*0.6*0.7*0.8*0.9`? Or what is the logic?

Comment: I updated the code currently running (and working). The theory comes from :  https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_2_1_union_bound_and_exten.php    I thought of recursion indeed, but had to limit my calculs (for time processing and costs purposes) so chose to keep at max 5 levels. If we have up to 4 levels I apply the exact formula otherwise I use the approximation one which gives a lower bound.

Comment: The numbre of levels is derived from probList (and has an upper limit of 5)

Comment: So the `slice` that you now do is dependent on the level? Would you do `slice(0, 5)` when level is 5? Are you sure that the default case at the end would not need another term? It seems less precise than for case 4...

Comment: BTW, there are new errors in your code now. `sort()` is mutating the original array and sorting alphabetically, not numerically. `product` is going to be zero always. The `default` case is never going to happen because you did `.slice(0, 4)`. You need to use `var` for all variables, otherwise they will be global, which is undesired.

Comment: Also, I don't see the logic why `product` is a term in `case 3` and `case 4`, but not in `case 1` or `case 2`. It seems all very arbitrary, which removes possibilities to reduce the code to something elegant.

Comment: In `case 3`, you'll have `intersection3/6` being equal to `product` (if correctly calculated), so `intersection3/6 - product` is going to be 0... What did you intend to add here? I have deleted my answer as my confusion is growing out of bounds :/

Comment: I'm trying to make it clearer, for now I have to understand why making a product of a simple array makes 0 in js, I'll update the post as soon as I get everything clear

Comment: You will always get product 0 in your code, because you are starting the reduce with 0, start it with 1

Comment: Why are you dividing each sum by the factorial of it's level? And why your product is not divided by the factorial? Also if you have only 4 entries intersection4 is always gonna be equal to the product

Comment: Also as per the documentation from the link you provided, there is an extra condition for each level `i < j < k < ...`

Comment: Quit luckily, my previous code worked because my indexes were wrong thus the final term (the product) would be in the last intersection. I added some explanation on the code hoping it will make what I want to achieve clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example follows the below equation from https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_2_1_union_bound_and_exten.php

```
P(⋃(i=1 => n)Ai)=∑(i=1 => n) P(Ai) − ∑(i<j) P(Ai ∩ Aj) + ∑(i<j<k) P(Ai ∩ Aj ∩ Ak) − ... +(−1)^n−1 P(⋂(i=1 => n) Ai)
```

I don't know the reason why you included factorials in the example you gave, but I didn't include factorials as they are not there in the above equation.

```
// Recursive function to update sums of each level
function updateSums(sums, probList, maxLevel, currentLevel = 1, currentProduct = 1, lastIndex = -1) {
  // Example case: maxLevel = 4, curentLevel = 3, path = { 1: 0, 2: 1 }, currentProduct = probList[0] * probList[1]
  // Loops through all entries except 0 and 1 and adds the products to sums[2], for each entry also calculates level 4 sums

  for (let i = lastIndex + 1; i < probList.length; i++) {
    const nextProduct = currentProduct * probList[i];
    sums[currentLevel - 1] += nextProduct;

    if (currentLevel < maxLevel) {
      // get the next level product sums for current product
      updateSums(sums, probList, maxLevel, currentLevel + 1, nextProduct, i);
    }
  }
}

// Main function
function inequality(probList) {
  probList = probList.sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0, 4);

  // Calculate maxLevel
  const maxLevel = probList.length;
  if (!maxLevel) return 0;

  // create am array of sums, each entry represents 1 level
  const sums = (new Array(maxLevel)).fill(0);
  updateSums(sums, probList, maxLevel);

  return sums.reduce((a, c, i) => {
    return a + ((i % 2) ? -1 : 1) * c;
  }, 0);
}

console.log(inequality(probList));
```

> PS: This is written in ES6

Comment: César introduced factorials because if you look at his loops, he starts from idx 0 so for a (i,j,k) he also handles (j,i,k),(j,k,i)... (the arrangement of 3 elems) hence 2!, 3!, 4!, ...depending on the nesting

Comment: Ohh got it, he is making permutations and converting them to combinations. If we can make sure there are no repetitions then the factorials are not needed. Thank you for explanation

Comment: Exactly, I actually changed that by using the inequality i<j<k<l as suggested above

Comment: I tried your code, but it would only give me 0 ... Otherwise, I agree on the fact that recursion solves the imbricated for loops problem.

Comment: Sorry small typo, change lastindex param to lastIndex = -1

Comment: It's a valid answer. I didn't use recursion to stop on purpose the process when the number of levels increases, but I can just pass it as an extra param in your function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We may avoid a recurrence

Say `A` of size `n`

According to your formula we may consider

- we take 1 element from A: `C_n^1`
- we take 2 elements from A: `C_n^2`
- we take 3 elements from A: `C_n^3`

Instead of recomputing every `k-utuple` (unordered tuple), we can simply keep the `(k-1)-utuples` of the previous layer
e.g let's take array [1,2,3,4,5]

- first layer: `1,2,3,4,5`
- second layer: `1-2`, `1-3`, `1-4`, `1-5`, `2-3`, `2-4`, ..., `4-5`
- third layer:  `1-2-{i}`(i for 3 to 5), `1-3-{i}`, ...

And for our case: we don't really need the whole utuple: just its last idx, and its value (product of its elems)

algo be like

```
function bonferroni(A, nlev){
    let lv = 0;
    let tot = 0;
    //i refers to the index of the last element added to the tuple
    //s refers to its value
    //here we initialize with i=-1 just so the first while loop builds an equivalent of "A"
    let layer = [{i:-1, s:1}];
    while(lv < nlev){
        let sum = 0;
        let next = [];
        layer.forEach(utuple=>{

            for(let i = utuple.i+1; i<A.length; ++i){
                let s = utuple.s * A[i];
                sum += s;
                next.push({i, s});
            }
        })
        layer = next;
        if((lv % 2)==0){
            tot += sum;
        }else{
            tot -= sum;
        }
        lv++;
    }
    return tot;
}
```

The verbose version being:

```js
function bonferroniVerbose(A, nlev){
    let lv = 0;
    let tot = 0;
    //i refers to the index of the last element added to the tuple
    //s refers to its value
    //here we initialize with i=-1 just so the first while loop builds an equivalent of "A"
    let layer = [{t:[], i:-1, s:1}];
    while(lv < nlev){
        console.log('--------------layer', lv);
        let sum = 0;
        let next = [];
        layer.forEach(utuple=>{

            for(let i = utuple.i+1; i<A.length; ++i){
                let s = utuple.s * A[i];
                sum += s;
                let t = utuple.t.concat(A[i]);
                next.push({t, i, s});
                console.log('summing', t.join('*'), '->', s);
            }
        })
        layer = next;
        if((lv % 2)==0){
            tot += sum;
        }else{
            tot -= sum;
        }
        lv++;
    }
    return tot;
}
console.log(bonferroniVerbose([1,2,3,4,5], 3))
```